# Prove that $\frac{1}{1 +\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}}+­...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99} +\sqrt{100}}=9$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove that $$\frac{1}{1 +\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}
> +\sqrt{3}}+­...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99} +\sqrt{100}}=9.$$

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i} +\sqrt{i+1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\sqrt{i} -\sqrt{i+1}}{2i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\sqrt{i}}{2i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\sqrt{i+1}}{2i+1}...$

I can not find the trick to break this summation. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Write out the two sums and see what cancels ... note the denominators are wrong - the difference of squares remember.

Comment: Are you sure about the second equality ?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Observe that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$$

and telescope.

Comment: Ok right, I did a mistake

Comment: No worry.  You had the right idea!  ;-))

Comment: I knew it was a telescopic series, but I couldn't unlock.

Comment: Well, you were on the right path.  You rationalized the denominator, but had a simple error when multiplying $(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k+1})$.  That was all.  Otherwise, you had it!  So, well done.

Answer (score 2):

I think your transformation of the sum is not correct. You rather have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}}{(i+1)-i}=\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}$$
Now, your sum should telescope and the rest should be easy, right?